# Should we cull content in community wiki omnibus Q&A's?

Tags: discussion, site-organization, community-wiki

I fear that omnibus Q&A's (is there an accepted term for these?) like [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/121) and [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/121) can grow too long to be genuinely useful, and they may have done so already.

When one is met with a wall of links, even a well organize one, there is undeniable content dilution.  Not all posts and not all elements of those posts are of equal importance.  In the case of *pitfalls* posts are at least voted up or down which provides a relative placement for those with that sort option selected, but these unpopular posts still take room in the index.  In the case of *examples* the *many* links in each post are not ranked by votes.

**I propose a culling process by which unpopular content is removed from these pages.**

For *pitfalls* this could be as simple as: if the post has not accrued *p* votes in *d* days (values to be determined) the post will be removed.

For *examples* this would be much harder.  However I think here it may be that much more important so that high quality references on popular topics are not lost among those of lower merit.  If others agree at least that this is a problem then we should consider if there is a practical approach to reviewing, ranking, and perhaps ultimately culling some of these many links.

Comment: If we would have a "documentation" section I'd argue for using that for this purpose. However, using http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wolfram-mathematica/topics could be an option worth discussing, although it would be completely outside of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com. (Do our moderators have any power there?)

Comment: [Stack Overflow Documentation - should we get in on this?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1935/18476)

Comment: Does this answer the question, for example: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118686/13162

Comment: I don't agree with culling those Q&As. I think it could actually be harmful. I like having canonical answers to refer to, and it's useful not just for the super common questions.

Comment: Can you, as a moderator, see how often a post is linked to? Removing a post could brake a lot of links.

Comment: @C.E.  In the case of *pitfalls* I am thinking of posts like [(119939)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119939/121) which are not merely uncommon but IMHO out of place.  Do we allow any post to remain because *one person* thinks it fits or do we as a community curate these to some extent?

Comment: @Karsten I don't believe that is a moderator function but it may be possible through http://data.stackexchange.com/ (for all users).  The kind of posts I envision culling (see my comment immediately above) would not be linked often.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't worry about *good examples* thread as it is for users who know, more or less, what they want to find. Or at least it is not a place you go when you are in hurry.

It is the opposite to *common pitfalls* which should be readable/searchable after a glimpse.

I agree we should not cut it but we should improve it, and my suggestion is to **make it friendly for users who don't read but scan**. Which is usually the case.

So I'd rephrase the table of contents:

## Old:

#### Syntax and semantics

- Basic syntax issues
- What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?
- Understand that semicolon (;) is not a delimiter
- Omitting ; can cause unexpected results in functions
- Understand the difference between Set (or =) and Equal (or ==)
- The displayed form may substantially differ from the internal form

---

## New:

#### Syntax and semantics

- Guide: variables, functions, definitions, equations...
- Guide: `@@`, `@@@`, `#`, `##`, `##2`, `_?f`, `%%` ...
- Tutorial: (`;`) semicolon role
- Tutorial: (`;`) when is semicolon needed
- Tutorial: `=` vs `==`
- Tutorial: `a + b` vs `Plus[a, b]` and replacements.
- Big picture: Coding in Mathematica

That is just an example but you get my point. So now the question is whether we proceed and, if so, how to decide what passes through.

Answer (score 5):

I see the problem, but I think I agree with C.E. that culling may not be the best solution. At least for pitfalls, which has been organized into sub-topics, we might break the mega-question it multiple questions -- one new question for each sub-topic.

I do worry that this proposed solution might break many established links. Perhaps such links could be updated? Since a lot of those links appear in comments, I fear the editing will put a great burden on moderators.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest, with one alternative: we leave the original in place, with it locked, and reset the links in the question to the new locations.

Comment: Where do I upvote (downvote) if I think we should leave those threads as they are?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP You mean no culling of any kind?  Post that an an Answer yourself, and others can vote for that position if they agree.

Comment: m_goldberg please see my comments below the question.  Links directly to answers would be broken by splitting up *pitfalls* and off-hand I do not think that is a good plan.  Culling early would prevent links from forming, and the kind of post I am thinking of isn't likely to be linked often anyway.

Comment: @Mr.W I realized that you meant removal of some lower-quality answers. I'd say I'm nonchalant about that. They don't get in my way, but I won't miss them if they go.

Answer (score 5):

In general I am not a fan of the *Pitfalls* question and would rather see single-topic canonical Q&A's for these common mistakes/confusions (like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica)) They could be united by a common tag to make them easy to locate.

However, I do appreciate that the community as a whole likes having a single target for the commonly duplicated questions, and it would break a **lot** of links to make any radical changes.

Therefore I support Mr.Wizard's proposal to cull unpopular content. The disruption will be minimal, and the remaining answers will address genuinely common problems. Culled posts need not be deleted outright if they have value, but could be moved to dedicated questions.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the *Examples* answers could be improved by removing most of the links to pages here on mathematica.stackexchange. The site itself already has functionality for finding content (search, tags), bookmarking useful pages (favorites) and identifying high quality material (votes). I question the usefulness of having these long lists of internal links.

If they were removed the remaining links would be more manageable and could be further culled or rearranged as necessary.